# How to change the location of the checkbox labels in SQLform

Tags: web2py, pydal

Is there an easy way to reposition the labels for checkboxes? I would like to show them on the left side in the same way as the other controls.

[image: Form with checkbox labels]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Tim for your answer. That told me everything I needed to know. Here is what I had to do:

1. Find the relevant function in the `gluon\sqlhtml.py`. For me it was `formstyle_bootstrap4_inline_factory`
2. Copy the `_inner` function which is in the `formstyle_boostrap4_inline_factory` function into my application and rename it `formstyle_myapp` (putting it in a model file is probably the easiest)
3. Copy the `add_class` function from `gluon.sqlhtml` and add it into `formstyle_myapp` function. This makes it visible to `formstyle_myapp` only.
4. Change the default `formstyle` setting in db.py to point to the new function: `response.formstyle = formstyle_myapp`
5. Finally, adjust the checkbox part of the `formstyle_myapp` to position the label on the left under all the other labels and the checkbox to the right under all the the other controls:

   ```
    elif controls['_type'] == 'checkbox' or controls['_type'] == 'radio':
        _controls = DIV(controls, _class="%s" % col_class)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make your own formstyle (copying formstyle_bootstrap3_inline_factory, which I'm guessing you're using)

Then cut out the rule treating checkboxes differently:

```
elif controls['_type'] == 'checkbox':
                label['_for'] = None
                label.insert(0, controls)
                label.insert(1, ' ')
                _controls = DIV(DIV(label, _help, _class="checkbox"),
                                _class="%s %s" % (offset_class, col_class))
                label = ''
```